# Using cin, if statement, and array not working

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, cin, cpu-registers

I am making a mini-CPU in C++ that uses binary states of an array to activate different events. For example, an array whose 67, 39, and 23th values are 1 might output the date. I was doing an input test where inputting "a" would cause the first actual value to be one. As you notice, the array already starts with "a", but that is an indicator of a certain section of the CPU.

I did EVERYTHING the bug reports told me to do, but they keep on sending the same results. If you want, I can send the debug.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char var a = 1 

    char myArray = {a, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    char var pushregister;  
    cin >> pushregister;

    if (pushregister == a) {
        myArray = {a, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    cout << myArray;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  `char myArray = {a, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};` and `myArray = {a, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` shouldn't even compile

Comment: `char var a = 1` (among other things) - Are you sure this compiles?

Comment: This is not C++.

Comment: It looks like you need a good grounding on C++'s syntax and rules.

Comment: If you want to play with *bytes*, I recommend using `uint8_t`, because `char` can be signed, unsigned or *char* depending on the compiler settings.

Comment: What is "`char var`" supposed to do and how is it different than without the `var`?

Comment: Thomas, that's what my compiler told me. If you want, I can send you the original code or the debug. I do have a decent, not professional but adequate background on C++. I simply started with a normal, clean, unrepetitive code, and ended up adding the char, adding the variable, shortening the array, and removing a ton of libraries that I heard would be useful. Let me try to post the debug, you will understand my frustration after that.

Comment: In function 'int main()':
 error: expected initializer before 'a' char var a = 1
 error: expected initializer before 'pushregister'
 char var pushregister;
error: 'pushregister' was not declared in this scope
cin >> pushregister;
note: suggested alternative: 'register'
cin >> pushregister; 'a' was not declared in this scope
     if(pushregister == a){
                        ^
'myArray' was not declared in this scope
         myArray = {a, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
         ^~~~~~~
 'myArray' was not declared in this scope
     cout << myArray;
             ^~~~~~~

Comment: All of them except the first one I do not understand the reason for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
string myArray= "a, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0";
int pushregister; cin >> pushregister;

if (pushregister == a) {
    myArray = "a, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0"; cout << myArray;
}
else {
    cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: you can easily write this type of code by using string.

Comment: I recommend 1) one statement per line. 2) Reformatting using the {} when editing.

Comment: Next time i am trying to follow your suggestion.I am beginner.Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You code doesn't look like C++.
Did you want something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
  uint8_t a = 1;
  uint8_t my_array[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  static const size_t my_array_capacity =
    sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0]);
  my_array[0] = a;

  uint8_t push_register;
  std::cin >> push_register;
  if (push_register == a)
  {
    my_array[1] = 1;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < my_array_capacity; ++i)
  {
    if (i > 0)
    {
      std::cout << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(my_array[i]);
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Some differences:
1. Arrays can't contain variables, they contain values.
2. Use `[]` to access array slots.
3. When printing `uint8_t`, cast to `unsigned int` to avoid `cout` treating the variable as a character.

Comment: i did the first one at first, that told me to add variables (not specifically but generally, told me they can not just contain values)